# PHP, PDO Stored Procedure return nothing or unchanged value

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo, out-parameters

i am using php with mysql.

My stored proc returns values via out parameter via Toad4MySQL but when it comes to php Pdo, it does not capture the return value.

here's my code

```
$validusername= 'x';
$validemail = 'x'; 
$validkey   = 'x';

$query = $pdo->prepare("Call InsertNewUser(:fullname, :usernamex, :email, :password, :con_password, @:validusername, @:validemail, @:validkey); ");

$query->bindParam(':fullname', $fullname , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':usernamex', $usernamex , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':con_password', $con_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':validusername', $validusername, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);
$query->bindParam(':validemail', $validemail , PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);
$query->bindParam(':validkey', $validkey   , PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);

$results = $query->  execute();

echo $validemail ; # returns x but not the value that i wanted.
```

Can anyone help me with this puzzle ?

My Stored Procedure code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS InsertNewUser;
CREATE PROCEDURE xxx.`InsertNewUser`(

 fullname varchar(255),
 username varchar(255),
 email_address varchar(255), 
 password varchar(255),
 con_password varchar(255),
 out validusername varchar(10),
 out validemail varchar(10),
 out validkey varchar(155)
)
BEGIN

  declare xcnt_1 int;
  declare xcnt_2 int;
    declare xkey varchar(155);
  set xkey = MD5(RAND());

  select count(*) into xcnt_1 from user where user.email_address = email_address;
  select count(*) into xcnt_2 from user where user.username = username;

    if xcnt_1 > 0  then
      set validemail = 'false';
    else 
      set validemail = 'true';
    end if;

     if xcnt_2 > 0  then
      set validusername = 'false';
    else 
      set validusername = 'true';
    end if;

    if xcnt_1 = 0 and xcnt_2 = 0 then

      set validkey = xkey;
      INSERT INTO user
      (user.fullname, user.username, user.email_address, user.password, user.con_password, user.md5validate) 
      VALUES
      (fullname, username, email_address, password, con_password, xkey);
    else
       set validkey = 'false';
    end if;
    commit;

END;
```

ah... finally solved this problem :

for some unknown reasons, i have to change the call statement to :

```
Call InsertNewUser(:fullname, :usernamex, :email, :password, :con_password, @validusername_global, @validemail_global, @validkey_global);
```

and use this line of codes to get the data...

```
$SQL = ' select @validusername_global as validusername, @validemail_global as validemail, @validkey_global as validkey';
$query = $pdo->query($SQL);

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Executing the PDO prepared statement won't have any effect on `$validemail`.

After `$results = $query->execute();`, try adding `print_r($query->fetchAll());` to get a better sense of what is being returned from MySQL to PHP when your PHP statement runs the MySQL stored procedure.

Keep in mind that `$results` is just going to be a boolean indicating whether or not the statement could be executed.

Comment: @Schwartzie, it SHOULD have an effect on it if it's an input/output parameter.

Comment: Look at Example #10 on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: On second thought, it's not that instructive. Mike's answer is a better fit.

Comment: Well, none of the ideas work.. i still can't get it to work no matter what i tried :( Out should be working but that's not the case..

Answer (score 1):

From the PDO manual:

> int $length
>
> Length of the data type.
>   To indicate that a parameter is an OUT
>   parameter from a stored procedure, you
>   must explicitly set the length.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

You have omitted this parameter, which would explain why it is not being used as an OUT parameter.

Comment: tried b4, it still does not return any value in my php but it returns on Toad.

Comment: Well it's still necessary, so you should keep it there just in case.

Comment: @Schwartzie and @diEcho, Anyway, thanks for the feedbacks. i got it working finally..  but i still do not understand why the "_global" must be added for it to work..

Answer (score 0):

if you set `$validemail=x` and  dont manipulate/change nothing with `$validemail`  in later code then obvioulsy echo `$validemail`  will returns `x`.? whats' wrong with that? either u missed to paste some code

Comment: i have $validemail=x to detect the change in value but for some uncertain reasons, it does not changed. My storedP returns true or false strings from Toad4MySQL but in my php, it does not do anything to bounded variable. echo $validemail should return true / false but not x.

Comment: but the code you show in your question not having that specific code which use `$validemail` except inserting into database

Comment: this is the header of my sp : CREATE PROCEDURE `InsertNewUser`(

 fullname varchar(255),
 username varchar(255),
 email_address varchar(255), 
 password varchar(255),
 con_password varchar(255),
 out validusername varchar(10),
 out validemail varchar(10),
 out validkey varchar(155)
)

Comment: @Melvin what means by `storedP`is that typo?? and i m sorry i am not familiar with`Toad4MySQL` what it do?? Please write desirable output??

Comment: i am using this software : http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/ to manage my mysql codes and queries.

Comment: @melvin; please update your question with the stored Procedure code; somebody will helps you sure. i m not expert in that, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your prepare statement, bind parameters and execute in try, catch blocks and see if PDO spits out any sort of error.